# How to Deploy 2 SPAs on the same Azure Web Service App

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a a server (.dontet) running on Azure Web Service App. And I have an SPA running on top of that that communicates with the REST APIs of said server. That SPA (JS, HTML, CSS) is being served by accessing the root url of said server. (something like https://my-server.azurewebsites.net)

Now I want to deploy an additional SPA (basically a more modern version) that talks to the same server and to the very same REST APIs as the "old" SPA.

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please refer [Host Multiple Application In a Single Azure App Service](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/host-multiple-application-in-a-single-azure-app-service)

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT Thanks for the reference. I tried this but I am only getting a 
{ 502: "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process"}

Comment: Remove forwardWindowsAuthToken from the web.config file under wwwroot.

Navigate to src/ProjectName/wwwroot
Open the web.config
In the httpPlatformremove the forwardWindowsAuthToken="true/false" property. Redeploy the app.

Comment: adding a setting:


WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE = 1



Some information about it can be found  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code).

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT my web.config is pretty simple. Mostly it contains 
 `<assemblyBinding>`. The only thing that might look releant is this `  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="httpplatformhandler" />
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="suave.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\REST-Server.dll" />
  </system.webServer>` 
But none of the props you mentioned

Comment: I have tried using the given link [Host Multiple Application In a Single Azure App Service](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/host-multiple-application-in-a-single-azure-app-service) , it is working fine for me

Comment: Please check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69acfb46-699e-4ff3-ad81-ca9524ce151d/azure-webappthe-specified-cgi-application-encountered-an-error-and-the-server-terminated-the?forum=aspdotnetcore) once.

Comment: You could try remote debugging (see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remotedebug)) or simply scan your logs using Kudu, which you can find on [websitename].scm.azurewebsites.net (replace [websitename] with what would normally be in [websitename].azurewebsites.net)

Comment: what is url you are trying to access ? Add one default file in the newly created folders.

Comment: yeah I want to access a newly created index.html in the newly created folder. 
There is no API call or anthing just the delivery of some HTML and associated CSS etc.

Comment: Create a sample html file in the newly created folders and access the url .              Ex : https://YourApplication.azurewebsites.net/Exterior/test.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240989/discussion-between-robkuz-and-harshithaveeramalla-mt).